# Getting a subcategories from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, foreign-keys, primary-key

Hey i have following problem: is it possible to get the categories sorted like that:

```
MAIN2
-sub21
-sub22
-sub23
--sub223
MAIN3
-sub31
-sub32
-sub33
MAIN4
-sub41
-sub42
-sub43
```

in one MySQL query? I know it will be nessesary to use foreign key but I have no idea how to merge the results.

Elements in a database table
[image]

Comment: format the question properly.. post your image here

Comment: first create a child to parent relationship table and then try to implement this (displaying results in hierarchical manner) in your codebehind instead of a single sql query

Comment: but if you just want the work done, add a new column `Lister` and manually input the hierarchical data into it. For ex: `MAIN1 -> a`, `sub11->aa`, `MAIN2 -> b`, `sub21 -> ba`, `sub22 -> bb`, `sub211 -> baa` etc etc
Order by `Lister`and your problem is solved :)